# If asa Cli gets too long, it automatically gets omitted as "$". Is there no way to stop this?

Tags: cisco-asa, cli

When saving logs in our environment, it is inconvenient to have a CLI omitted as $, so as the title suggests, I would like to prevent $ from being omitted when entering CLI or marking it, is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. CLI and logs are different things. And the ASA does not chop log messages. Your terminal program might not "wrap to screen".

Comment: @Ricky Sorry I meant when I got the log shown on the console in teraterm.

Comment: Find where line wrap is turned off / disabled in teraterm. This isn't the ASA doing this. Your terminal application is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how it will affect your log output, it probably depends on how you are collecting the logs but you can try the `terminal width 0` command at various locations (config terminal or exec terminal) and see how affects the output. You can also set it much wider, like 500 and see how that works for you. It might need massaging to fit your needs.

Comment: Thx for the reply. I am using Cisco Firepower 2100 Series and 4100 Series... and there is no 'terminal width' command. Does that also work using 'terminal pager' command?

Comment: In that case, you might have to get into whatever they call the ASA command line portion of the Firepower platform. Flexconfig if I remember correctly. The Flexconfig environment is essentially the 'leftovers' of the ASA code that have not yet been migrated to the Firepower platform code so you might find the terminal width command there but whether it fixes your issue is hard to say. Cisco says some of the Flexconfig stuff is unpredictable.